# Trying to display to student data from file according to sorted student ID

Tags: c, file, sorting, file-handling

I am not able to sort the data i am fetching from file, i want it to print to console by ascending order of ID, I am not able to convert char ID to integer ID to compare

```
struct student{
    char ID[15];
    char name[20];
    char add[20];
    char parname[20];
    int Class;
    float gpa;
    long unsigned int phone_no;
};
void sort_accord_id()
{
    while(fread(&stu,sizeof(stu),1,fp))
{
    strcpy(s[count].ID,stu.ID);
    strcpy(s[count].name,stu.name);
    printf("ID:%s\n", stu.ID);

    printf("\t%s",s[count].ID);
    printf("\t%s",s[count].name);
    count++;
}



for(i=0;i<=count-1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=count-1;j++)
    {
        if(s[j].ID-'0'<s[j+1].ID-'0')
        {
            temp=s[j];
            s[j]=s[j+1];
            s[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: Is it printing at all? Also, where did you try to use strcmp()?

Comment: @Mini i did use it for other purpose and works fine if you can tell me about this please do

Comment: I am writing an answer right now

Answer (score 1):

If it is reading properly to (what I'm assuming to be) the student struct 'object' `stu`, one approach would be to keep them all in an array (dynamically allocated on heap would be best, otherwise just large enough to keep them all [careful with that!]), then sort them with `stdlib.h`'s `qsort()`.

I can offer help on dynamic arrays if you want but some googling would also do the trick I'm sure.

If you had an array of student structs (which I also suggest you typedef, but for the sake of this answer's clarity I won't) called `arr`, you could sort them like so:

- First `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of your file
- Then the following function to compare their ID's with strcmp:

  ```
  int student_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
  {
      struct student* studentA = (struct student*)a;
      struct student* studentB = (struct student*)b;

      return strcmp(studentA->ID, studentB->ID);
  }
  ```
- And finally, you can call `qsort` in your `sort_accord_id()` like so:

  `qsort(arr, 2, sizeof(struct student), student_cmp);`

Let me know if you have other questions. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i have done a little bit of modification  myself, i have made structure array-------- struct student s[20] and then i am accessing strcut attributes like this s[20].ID now the  only problem is i just need to sort them acccording to ID but it is of char type i cant know last ID is greater or smaller than previous one, i have made amendments in question  please have a look